# Debian & PostgreSQL - [ASSERT] Assertion failed for PostgreSQL Cluster 14

Tags: debian, postgresql

Right after booting Debian server I get this error:

> [ASSERT] Assertion failed for PostgreSQL Cluster 14.

[image: [ASSERT] assertion failed for postgresql cluster 14]

my PostgreSQL is active (I checked this by this command: `systemctl status postgresql@14-main.service`)

[image]

I googled and find this post:
[Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main when booting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591784/5649590)
but everything was fine with me:

[image]

and I googled more but couldn't find anything that work for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You should check path to your cluster configuration file, for proper permissions

```
$ ls -l /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 1005 Oct  3 16:07 /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
```

On Debian the systemd service unit `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service` contains following:

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
AssertPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
```

Basicaly the error message tells you that `/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf` can't be found. `%I` should be interpolated to `14/main`, thus systemd has troubles reading `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: and when you have a cluster with a dash "-" in the name.. then all SystemD hell breaks loose on that line :D
yes, changing the dash to an underscore fixed it
Perhaps I should log a bug against Debian to moan at the upstream? 0_o

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error "Assertion failed on job for postgresql@14.service." was due to trying to start the wrong service name (postgresql@14):  When I use the correct name (postgresql@14-main) it works as expected.  Maybe you enabled the wrong service to start at boot.

Answer (score 1):

I have this ultimate hate relationship with SystemD - several tickets opened against it that Lennard Poetering just shrug on and and....

That said: The problem i *MY* case was the freaking name it seems: `client-pg15-01`
the SystemD does substitutions etc. etc. on service names and filenames when it sees spaces dashes etc. and there are horrific rules (yes I'm exasperating as it's annoying for a server operator compared to a desktop/laptop jockey) so the long winded answer is to not confuse the regular expressions for this, and rather give simple names like `clientnamepg15number01` without any thing that can confuse the services names